# Change color of product backlog item depending of parent Feature

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We want to be able to see quickly from what feature does a PBI comes. Changing the color of the card seems to make everyone happy. I can't find any "Parent" choice when looking in the styling rules of the board. Is there a way to do it, or a better way to give vision to the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the card color filter, it can only be filtered by fields now. The parent/child work item can’t be filtered.

I posted an user voice [Enable to filter parent/child work items in WIT Board Styling rule](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31410967-enable-to-filter-parent-child-work-items-in-wit-bo) for this feature, you can vote and follow up.